# How to build File from image url

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I'm trying to make drag-n-drop functionality to load images on the site. Most of the tutorials show how to drag images from your local computers. But I need also to drag them from other pages from other hosts.

As I understand I need to first load image into blob and then using FileAPI upload it to my server.

I can't send just url to server instead of blob, because image can be on private site, and my server don't have an access to it.

Or maybe there is a way to build File object from `<img>` element?

This one example doesn't work because of cross origin ajax restrictions.
https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-22/downloading-a-blob-with